# Human readable string of 64bits time_t value

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit, ctime

I'm trying to print out the date, in a human readable format, for the maximum time_t value possible.
The following code seems to work just fine on 32bits machines (initializing m_time with 0x7fffffff), but it outputs null for the theoretically highest value on a 64bits machine. Is that a ctime limitation or am I missing something?

compilation : gcc -Wall -g3 main.c -o time_test
host machine: x86_64.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  time_t m_time = 0x7fffffffffffffff;
  time_t current_time;
  time(&current_time);

  printf("time_t info: sizeof [%ld] bytes or [%ld] bits.\n", sizeof(time_t), sizeof(time_t) *8 );
  printf("m_time val: [%ld]-> %s\n", m_time, ctime(&m_time)); 
  printf("current_time val: [%ld]-> %s\n", current_time, ctime(&current_time));
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
time_t info: sizeof [8] bytes or [64] bits.
m_time val: [9223372036854775807]-> (null)
current_time val: [1430678274]-> Sun May  3 15:37:54 2015
```

tks.

Comment: "When encountering an error, these functions return `NULL` and set `errno` to an appropriate value." What does `perror` say?

Comment: Indeed there is an error. Error:  Invalid argument.

Comment: Pragmatically, if `time_t` has more than 40 bits (e.g. 64 bits) you don't care about the maximally representable time. You and everyone reading that forum (and all our grand grand children) would be dead, the computers running your program will all be destroyed, and at that time C won't exist anymore. The [Y2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) don't practically have any 64 bits equivalent. So just special case `time_t` is 32 bits.

Comment: Well, it could report a date 292 billion years in the future.  Or it could assume there won't be anybody around anymore to run your program.  What would you do?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, but your code can be so, so good, that it survives the pass of time, even to that time.  Just kidding, don't flame me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BTW, [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/ctime/) (& [ctime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html)) is documented as giving a string with the year represented by *four* digits (for a total of 26 bytes). So the maximal time is in the year 9999 (certainly less than maximal `time_t` on a machine with 64 bits `time_t`).

Also (as I commented),  pragmatically, if `time_t` has more than 40 bits (e.g. 64 bits) you don't care about the maximally representable time. You and everyone reading that forum (and all our grand grand children) would be dead, the computers running your program will all be destroyed, and at that time C won't exist anymore. The [Y2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) don't practically have any 64 bits equivalent. So just special case when `time_t` is 32 bits.

<sup>It is very unlikely than any C program would matter after the year 3000; software, hardware, standards, and human technical expertise don't last that long...</sup>

The [POSIX ctime documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) says *explicitly* :

> Attempts to use `ctime()` or `ctime_r()` for times before the Epoch or for times beyond the year 9999 produce *undefined results*. Refer to [asctime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/asctime.html#).

BTW, [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) seems to be conformant to the standard: [its `time/__asctime.c`](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/time/__asctime.c) (indirectly called by `ctime`) has a nice comment:

```
if (snprintf(buf, 26, "%.3s %.3s%3d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d %d\n",
    __nl_langinfo(ABDAY_1+tm->tm_wday),
    __nl_langinfo(ABMON_1+tm->tm_mon),
    tm->tm_mday, tm->tm_hour,
    tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec,
    1900 + tm->tm_year) >= 26)
{
    /* ISO C requires us to use the above format string,
     * even if it will not fit in the buffer. Thus asctime_r
     * is _supposed_ to crash if the fields in tm are too large.
     * We follow this behavior and crash "gracefully" to warn
     * application developers that they may not be so lucky
     * on other implementations (e.g. stack smashing..).
     */
    a_crash();
}
```

and GNU `glibc` has in its [time/asctime.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=time/asctime.c;hb=HEAD) file:

```
/* We limit the size of the year which can be printed.  Using the %d
   format specifier used the addition of 1900 would overflow the
   number and a negative vaue is printed.  For some architectures we
   could in theory use %ld or an evern larger integer format but
   this would mean the output needs more space.  This would not be a
   problem if the 'asctime_r' interface would be defined sanely and
   a buffer size would be passed.  */
if (__glibc_unlikely (tp->tm_year > INT_MAX - 1900))
  {
  eoverflow:
    __set_errno (EOVERFLOW);
    return NULL;
  }

int n = __snprintf (buf, buflen, format,
          (tp->tm_wday < 0 || tp->tm_wday >= 7 ?
           "???" : ab_day_name (tp->tm_wday)),
          (tp->tm_mon < 0 || tp->tm_mon >= 12 ?
           "???" : ab_month_name (tp->tm_mon)),
          tp->tm_mday, tp->tm_hour, tp->tm_min,
            tp->tm_sec, 1900 + tp->tm_year);
if (n < 0)
 return NULL;
if (n >= buflen)
  goto eoverflow;
```

So I believe that both GNU glibc and musl-libc are better than MacOSX implementation (as cited in [zneak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30018023/841108)) on that aspect. The standards requires `ctime` to give 26 bytes. Also, **POSIX 2008 is marking `ctime` as *obsolete***, new code should use [strftime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) (see also [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)).

Comment: Weird, [`asctime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/asctime.html#) (same reference) makes no mention to year 9999, and instead says that the result is undefined if `tm_year` is larger than `{INT_MAX}-1990`. What may cause UB is that the result buffer is defined to be 26 bytes. This is not an issue with `asctime_r`, and should neither be with `ctime_r`.

Answer (score 2):

To get to the bottom of this, the best idea is to find an implementation and look at what it does. I downloaded Apple's [`Libc` tarball for OS X 10.1.1](http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/Libc/Libc-1044.1.2.tar.gz) (whose link can be found on [this page](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-10101/)), and found that `ctime` is defined in stdtime/FreeBSD/localtime.c.

The function goes like this:

```
char *
ctime(timep)
const time_t * const    timep;
{
/*
** Section 4.12.3.2 of X3.159-1989 requires that
**  The ctime function converts the calendar time pointed to by timer
**  to local time in the form of a string.  It is equivalent to
**      asctime(localtime(timer))
*/
#ifdef __LP64__
    /*
     * In 64-bit, the timep value may produce a time value with a year
     * that exceeds 32-bits in size (won't fit in struct tm), so localtime
     * will return NULL.
     */
    struct tm *tm = localtime(timep);

    if (tm == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return asctime(tm);
#else /* !__LP64__ */
    return asctime(localtime(timep));
#endif /* __LP64__ */
}
```

From a [second-hand reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/), `struct tm` appears to be defined in terms of integers, and the `tm_year` field is an offset from 1900. Assuming conformance to that, even a non-conforming `ctime` cannot possibly accept a timestamp after year 2<sup>31</sup>+1900-1.

Here is a program that finds (and tests) the largest timestamp `ctime` will accept with Apple's implementation:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct tm t = {
        .tm_sec = 59,
        .tm_min = 59,
        .tm_hour = 23,
        .tm_mday = 31,
        .tm_mon = 11,
        .tm_year = INT_MAX,
    };
    time_t max = mktime(&t);

    printf("Maximum time: %li\n", max);
    printf("ctime max: %s\n", ctime(&max));
    max++;
    printf("ctime max+1: %s\n", ctime(&max));
}
```

Output:

> Maximum time: 67768036191694799
>   ctime max: Wed Dec 31 23:59:59     2147485547
>   ctime max+1: (null)

This is a 56-bit number, so the maximum year a 64-bit `time_t` can hold (though `struct tm` can't) is probably between 547,608,814,485 and 549,756,300,032, or like 36 times the age of the universe. In other words, it's going to be a while.

For what it's worth, Apple's implementation is not conforming. The standard says that the output of `ctime` has to fit inside 26 bytes, including a newline character and a null character. For a conforming implementation, this means that the year has to be within -999 and 9999.